# Reading pdf contents using Python

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-reader

I am trying to read the below pdf file and I need to save each and every article in seperate file.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23092311/sample.pdf

A article can be in one or more than one pages. I have used PDFMiner to convert the entire pdf to txt file. But I don't know how to convert into multiple articles.

I am new to Python. Please provide a best method or sample code to extract the each and every articles separately?

Comment: Here is my email: kannan4k@gmail.com Thanks devnull

Comment: Hi devnull , I am waiting for your response! Please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll be honest.  I've never used PDFMiner before, but if you already have the PDF into a text file, couldn't you just parse the text file into a string, and then use the [split function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) to divide the string into different articles based on "The New York Times" heading?  I guess that assumes PDFMiner is capable of reading that fancy font which I don't know if that is possible.

Looking at the file you provided, you could something like the following:

```
reading = open('test.txt')
full_paper = reading.read()
split_paper = full_paper.split('Copyright 2014 The New York Times Company. All Rights Reserved.')
```

split_paper would then be an array containing your articles in indexes 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 (index 0 would contain the initial heading).  You'd have to do some other string cleanup to get the exact articles, but that should at least get you started.

Make sense?

Comment: Please find the corresponding text file. 
https://github.com/kannan4k/Sentimental-Analysis-in-Python/blob/master/sample.txt

Comment: Updated initial comment.  Let me know if you have any questions.